# Trouble getting value from form element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm building basically a visually appealing version of an option-select element.

I'm making a ul that will have a .selected class applied to whatever item is clicked.

```
            <ul id="videolist" class="tilelist"> 
                <li id="video-'. $video-id .'">
                        <img src="assetsPath/etc/'. $video-thumb .'" />
                        <h4>'. $video-title .'</h4>
                        <p class="hidden vid-id">'. $video-id .'</p>
                    </li>
                ';} ?>
            </ul>

            <input id="videoId" class="hidden" value="<?php echo $current->video ?>" />
```

and then some jquery:

```
$(function(){

    $('#videolist li').click( function() {

        $('#videolist li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var vidId = $(this).find('.vid-id').val();
        alert (vidId);
        $('#videoId').val( vidId );
    }); 
});
```

the issue is with `$(this).find('.vid-id').val();` doesn't seem to be returning anything. I don't see anything wrong with the selector but I am a bit new to jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `text()` not `val()` if you are meaning to pull this from the `p` tag.

If you want to pull it from the `input` you're going to have to select the id like this: `$(this).find('#videoId').val();`

Also, you don't need to add css properties to hide the input, you can just do `type="hidden"`

Comment: yup. thanks! I'm thinking of trying to generecize that into a function, is there a way to reference either value/text automatically or does it get wonky bc some elements could potentially have both?

Comment: I would separate it into two different functions. Having multiple jobs for a single function is not a good idea.